# How to refresh Jquery datatables in order to account for newly added rows?

Tags: jquery, datatables

I do a json request and fill up a table in the dom with rows and then call .DataTable() to make it a datable. I do this instead of an ajax call for various reasons.

Now I want to add rows to this table (by manipulating the dom and adding the rows manually). How can I 'refresh' or 'reload' the datatables to account for these new rows?

Thanks!

Comment: https://datatables.net/examples/api/add_row.html

Comment: You'd need to add the rows to the datasource and call `fnDraw()` to refresh the datatable.  That way the new rows will be included in the paging & sorting etc.

Comment: add row works but I want to add the rows myself as they contain other data which add row won't account for.

@markpsmith by 'add the rows to the datasource' what do you mean? to the dom?

Comment: You can't add to DOM, you aren't recognizing that there is a lot more to the plugin than just dom manipulation. It has internal caches that you are trying to bypass. Use the render callbacks within column definitions to modify specific cells based on data

Comment: Your datasource is the json object in the DOM - is that right?  If you showed your datatables initialisation code it would help.

Comment: I understand that, but what I want to do is to change the DOM and then completely reload the datatable. Like what happens when it is first loaded. I think I've got it though, I destroy it and then initialize it again, seems like it works.

Answer (score 0):

When I need to reinitalise a dataTable, I use the destroy() method. Then I re-initialise it as normal.

```
var table = $("#table").DataTable();

// Table is updated 
addRow();

// Destroy outdated table
table.destroy();

// Create a new instance of dataTables
table = $("#table").DataTable();
```